# Fading ticker with timeout delay (setInterval inside setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, ticker

I want to make a top 10 list where it updates to another set of top 10 list, but tickering the whole list to another is way too boring and simple.

What I want is to fade out then change each position one after another from top 1 to top 10.

I lack knowledge on javascript/jquery. but if my logic is right it only needs a 1 sec. timeout delay on each position and each position has the same interval delay changing one to another.

Answer (score 0):

### Try *jQuery* for animations

I'd suggest using jQuery for animations to fade elements in and out as well as animations, which it sounds like you're asking about.

---

**jQuery** *— Fade controls.*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').fadeToggle('slow'); //Fade in or out based on CSS display:.
    $('div').fadeOut('slow'); //Fade an element (div) out.
    $('div').fadeIn('slow'); //Fade an element (div) in.
});
```

**jQuery** *— Slide controls.*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').slideToggle('slow'); //Slide in or out based on CSS display:.
    $('div').slideOut('slow'); //Slide an element (div) out.
    $('div').slideIn('slow'); //Slide an element (div) in.
});
```

**jQuery** *— Delay an animation.*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').delay(500).slideToggle('slow'); //Slide in or out based on CSS display: after half a second.
});
```